# Targets within a target in a Podfile

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to install the Google Mobile Ads SKD into my Xcode project. I installed Cocoapods and then initialized a Podfile into my project:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.2'

target 'Cubical' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Cubical

  target 'CubicalTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'CubicalUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

However, I don't understand why there are targets within my main project (Cubical). I never really used CubicalTests or CubicalUITests, since I don't really need to test my UI or any snippet of code. **I was thinking of removing these two folders.**

My questions are,

**1) Is there any drawback in removing the Tests and UITests folders from my Xcode project? And if I do, can I just simply delete those two targets from my Podfile?**

**2) Let's say I was going to keep those two targets. Would I have to add the pod to all three targets? Or do the two nested targets inherit any pods of target 'Cubical'**

**3) Do I need to add to Linked Frameworks the Google Mobile Ads SDK? Or is this already done by Cocoapods?**

My final pod would look like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.2'

target 'Cubical' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

  # Pods for Cubical

  target 'CubicalTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'CubicalUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Question 1:**

There is no issue when you are removing `Tests`,`CubicalUITests` targets & folders, If you don't need to perform that kind of tests.

**Question 2**:

You can share pods with several targets like below,

```
def shared
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
end

target 'Target1' do
shared
end

target 'Terget2' do
shared
end
```

**Global pods for multiple targets**

```
#Global Pod for all targets
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

target 'target1' do
    pod 'Fabric' #Pod for nested Target. i.e., Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK + Fabric
end

target 'target2' do
 pod 'RadioButton'#Pod for nested Target. i.e., Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK + RadioButton
end
```

**Pods for nested targets:**

```
#Global Pod for all targets
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

target 'target1' do
   pod 'RadioButton' #Available for target1 and target2
   target 'target2 copy' do 
      pod 'Fabric' #Available for target2 only
   end
end
```

**Question 3:**

The linked frameworks are automatically done by cocoapods. See [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/) you need to link the framework by using frameworks without cocoapods.

Comment: Amazing answer, but then what is the difference between nested targets and global targets? (if that is even the proper nomenclature, not that experience with Ruby)